# Why are my CSS Sprites not working?

Tags: css, css-sprites

Just testing out CSS sprites and cannot get them working for some reason.

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/VYWxbM

HTML:

```
<i class="icon-electrical14"></i>
<i class="icon-hazelnut1"></i>
<i class="icon-megaphone10"></i>
<i class="icon-winds2"></i>
```

CSS:

```
.icon-electrical14 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEIxDuO.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.icon-hazelnut1 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEIxDuO.png);
  background-position: -64px 0px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.icon-megaphone10 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEIxDuO.png);
  background-position: 0px -64px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 56px;
}
.icon-winds2 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEIxDuO.png);
  background-position: -64px -64px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 52px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Apply `display: block` or `inline-block` to `i`.

**[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEZjZp)**

```css
i[class*="icon-"] {
  display: block;
}
.icon-electrical14 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEIxDuO.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.icon-hazelnut1 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEIxDuO.png);
  background-position: -64px 0px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.icon-megaphone10 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEIxDuO.png);
  background-position: 0px -64px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 56px;
}
.icon-winds2 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/CEIxDuO.png);
  background-position: -64px -64px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 52px;
}
```

```html
<i class="icon-electrical14"></i>
<i class="icon-hazelnut1"></i>
<i class="icon-megaphone10"></i>
<i class="icon-winds2"></i>
```

---

*Side Note*: If you have some `i` tags dedicated to fonts and not icons on your page, you could use the following selector to select the classes that has `icon` keyword in the `class` attribute.

```
i[class*="icon"] {....}
```